# What to do when product logo and company logo don't match

Tags: color, logo

I am designing a promotional DVD. It is advertising a product, that has a red (`#ed1c24`) and black logo. The company logo, however, is a soft blue  (`#508dd1`)and black. How can I include both of these elements on the disc even though they don't match?

I have tried different positioning, as well as gray-scaling the company logo, but it really takes away a lot from the company logo.

Here's a really rough mockup of what I'm working with.

[image]

Comment: Looks fine to me! Red and blue are generally colors that *do* match.

Comment: I agree with CAI, that looks like it will work perfectly well once you've finished the design. It doesn't look like it clashes at all.

Comment: I guess before I had the logo on the right side of the disc actually, so the balance was much more off. But in general, even though these colors seem ok to everyone else, the question still stands :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with CAI's comment that the logos look fine on the CD.

> How can I include both of these elements on the disc even though they
>   don't match?

I don't think you can do anything about it and I wouldn't alter a logo unless it was ok based on the companies branding guideline. It does help if you're working with a neutral colored background.

I mostly work on projects that use multiple logos on the same design. I am usually provided company logos that very much clash in style and/or colors. But I cannot just change the logo colors because they do not match the design I have created or because the logos do not match the other logos in the design. A logo is not just apart of the design, it is there to represent the company.

Answer (score 0):

Find the connecting color. This is probably a medium purple. Use this color in between, or use a red-purple-blue gradient.